# i want to access doctrine 2 DBAL from within zend 2 for a native sql query

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i am using zend 2 an doctrine 2 on my site. i want however  to make a native sql query and therefore need a mysql connection.

i understand that doctrine 2 gives this via the DBAL

i refer to Mark Robison [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/symfony2/xfd5jLREgj4)

> Doctrine 2 ORM uses the Doctrine 2 DBAL, which is a thin but useful
>   wrapper around the PDO database layer. You can retrieve that from the
>   service container (it's called "database_connection", and give it
>   whatever SQL you want, CASE and all. e.g. in your controller

:

```
$dbal = $this->get('database_connection');
$stmt = $dbal->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = :baz');
$stmt->bindValue('baz', 'qux');
```

i am able to access my entity manager via;

```
public function getEntityManager()
        {
            if (null === $this->em) {
                $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
            }
            return $this->em;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the question is actually asking.  You can use the same approach that you used for getting the entity manager.  Just need to change the service id:

```
public function getConnection() {
  if (null === $this->conn) {
    $this->conn = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('database_connection');
  }
  return $this->conn;
}
```

By the way, using a local variable to cache the results is probably a waste of code.  Just pull it from the service locator when you need it.

Or, if you already have the entity manager, then a simple:

```
$connection = $entityManager->getConnection();
```

Might want to read up a bit on what the dbal connection object actually is and how to use it.

http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html

Answer (score 3):

You can run a native query using your `EntityManager` and a `ResultMapping` instance like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$entityManager = $htis->getEntityManager();
$query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery(
    'SELECT id, name, discr FROM users WHERE name = ?', $rsm
);
$query->setParameter(1, 'romanb');

$users = $query->getResult();
```

This comes [straight from the documentation of Doctrine 2](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class)

But you can also use other solutions like [DQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) or [use the EntityManager directly to find objects](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/working-with-objects.html)